# how to go back to main hash after click refresh button?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I use backbone.js for my project, it is a one page website.

I want to ask how can i go back to the main URL after refreshing.

For example, the main URL is

http://example.dev/#

other URL are

http://example.dev/#contact, http://example.dev/#about

Now, if the URL is on http://example.dev/#contact, I would like the URL go back to http://example.dev/# after i click refresh button.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

you could use `onbeforeunload` event for this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```

Comment: It does not work. The URL does not change after i click refresh button or press F5. Don't know why it does not work :(